# How to project a 2d array on Basemap using python?

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to display data on a map using python's basemap library. The data I have is in a 2D array (72 X 144). I have been able to get a map to show but when I display the data on the map, it looks as like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zsw9Y.png

My question is how can I show the data so it expands the entire map? I don't know how to get change the size of the map.

My code is shown below:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
from pylab import *
from matplotlib import colors
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

A = np.fromfile('1983/yyyymmddhh.83100100', dtype='int32')
B = np.reshape(A, (72, 144))

for i, n in enumerate(B):
    for j, m in enumerate(n):
        if (B[i][j] == -999):
            B[i][j] = 13

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

m = Basemap(projection='cyl', lat_0 = 50, lon_0 = -100,
            ax = ax, resolution = 'l',
            llcrnrlat=-90, urcrnrlat = 90, llcrnrlon = -180, urcrnrlon = 180)

border_color = 'black'
m.drawcoastlines()

plt.imshow(B)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Try `m.imshow` rather than `plt.imshow`: http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html#mpl_toolkits.basemap.Basemap.imshow

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to do this, as you can see here; http://matplotlib.org/basemap/api/basemap_api.html

The first, listed in the comments above, is to use m.imshow.

Next, you can plot a pseudocolor image with m.pcolor, or m.pcolormesh, by specifying the lat/lon coordinates for each point; this will color squares.

Lastly, you can display a contour map using contour, or filled countour map, using m.contour or m.countourf.